# Как найти в дереве файлов(Solution Explorer) открытый в VisualStudio конкретный файл?

Tags: visual-studio

Я работал с `AndroidStudio` и там была очень удобная кнопка которая срату тебя перемещала на нужный тебе файл в дереве проекта

Скажем у вас есть слева(или справа) дерево всего вашего solution там может быть несколько проектов, модулей и все такое и естественно количество доступных файлов может быть тысячи... и вот скажем я работаю сейчас в каком то конктретном файле и хочу найти его в дереве проекта и мне нужно среди этой тысячи файлов глазами пытаться найти его соглано его нахождению в проекте и алфавита...

Вопрос - есть ли какае то кнопка(как это в AndroidStudio если кто знаком) или hot keys который нужно набрать, чтоб курсов автоматически переместился на нужный тебе файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обозревателе решений есть кнопка с двумя стрелками:
[image: Синхронизировать с активным документом]

При задержке курсора над ней можно увидеть комбинацию горячих клавиш.